# How much does potato starch affect a cheese sauce recipe?

Tags: sauce, cheese

I'm following this recipe for making cheese sauce:

- (text) https://www.allrecipes.com/recipe/229731/homemade-nacho-cheese-sauce/
- (video) https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JMw4Q1RMD6I

While purchasing the ingredients I noticed something about pre-shredded cheese versus a block (Kraft brands); they are exactly the same via the Ingredients list on the package except the pre-shredded cheese has added an unspecified amount of potato starch.

Will this affect the amount of flour (or other ingredients) required or even make the product not come out as intended?

Comment: Easy solution: don't buy pre-shredded cheese.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hmm I suppose they add starch to keep it from turning back into one block of cheese.

Thing to do is if the sauce looks to thick just add more milk.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it can slightly affect the texture of your sauce... how much depends on how powdery it is. It basically acts like you added a little more flour than you did. The only thing that you might need to change is the overall amount of liquid in the sauce, and it can be easily adjusted after cooking. Follow the recipe as you would have previously, and if it looks a little thick, throw a little liquid in there. I can't give you more specific advice because the video is dead.

Answer (score -2):

Not a chance theres enough potato starch to change anything. I cant see the recipe but believe me I have made more mac and cheese then the average human. I always  use pre-shredded. Good luck